hide the underline react-syntax-highlighter
I want to hide the underline for java code
can some one help me ?
import {PrismLight as SyntaxHighlighter} from 'react-syntax-highlighter';
import atomDark from 'react-syntax-highlighter/dist/cjs/styles/prism/atom-dark;
import java from 'react-syntax-highlighter/dist/cjs/languages/prism/java;
SyntaxHighlighter.registerLanguage('java', java);
  code(code) {
            const {className, children} = code;
            const language = className.split('-')[1]; // className is something like language-js => We need the "js" part here
            return (
                <SyntaxHighlighter
                    style={atomDark}
                    language={language}
                    children={children}
                />
            );
        }



To hide the underline in the React Syntax Highlighter, you can customize the CSS by using the style or className properties to override the default text-decoration.
  <SyntaxHighlighter 
  language="javascript" 
  style={{ textDecoration: 'none' }}>
  {codeString}
</SyntaxHighlighter>

or
.no-underline {
  text-decoration: none !important;
}

<SyntaxHighlighter 
  language="javascript" 
  className="no-underline">
  {codeString}
</SyntaxHighlighter>


I know that setting text-decoration to none will do the trick but style attribute is assigned to   atomDark . How to apply both atomDark and text-decoration :none styles ? I want both styles to be applied

const updatedStyles = {...atomDark,textDecoration: 'none'} then use this  as prop             style={updatedStyles}

First of all I checked to which class was the text-decoration:underline
was being applied in the web developer tools then I  added this to global.css which solved the problem
.token {
 text-decoration: none !important;
}

